# 3d animated show with main girl character that i think had a somewhat asian complexion and had water related powers

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

A few years ago (maybe 6 or 7) I watched this 3d animated show with this main girl character with straight black hair and she wasn't really old maybe a pre teen. And I'm not so sure because it was a long time ago and only watched it once but I think she lived on an island and had some friends and maybe a grandfather or something. I think she was this lost princess because only she had these special powers where she could breathe underwater and had many adventures there. I also vaguely remember the opening song was this kind of weird holy magical watery? sound and it showed the underwater world and some flashes of the episodes.

Comment: You might want to mention that you've asked this question elsewhere; https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/query.php?parent_id=88768&type=ykts

Comment: You might also want to mention that other contributors suggested *The New Adventures of Ocean Girl* and *Magic Wonderland*

Comment: thank you for reminding me that i posted this question somewhere else because i couldn't find it again since i posted it a while ago. thank you so much :)